# Highlight a phrase globally in the open document when double clicked in Geany

Tags: ide, highlighting, geany

Is there an option to turn this on somewhere? Similar behaviour can be found in Notepad++ for example. Useful for immediately seeing where stuff gets used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind, it's available in the pre-installed plugin 'addons' as Mark-Word

http://plugins.geany.org/addons.html#mark-word

Answer (score 0):

For me it didn't work (under Fedora), but [GeanyHighlightSelectedWord](http://sourceforge.net/projects/geanyhighlightselectedword/) did.